# Projective space, $S^n$

Tags: algebraic-topology

> We observe the projective space $\mathbb{R}P^n$ for $n>1$. Let $e\in S^n$ be random.
>
> a) The quotient map $p:S^n\to\mathbb{R}P^n$ is an overlapping and $U_i:=\{p(x):x\in S^n, x_i\neq 0\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}P^n$ is for every $i=1,..., n$ a "trivial set"

(I give the definition of "trivial set" below, because I do not know the exact translation)

> b) It exists a path $\tilde{w}$ from $-e$ to $e$.

Hello,

I have some problems with this task and would be thankfull for your help.

to a):

It is $\mathbb{R}P^n$ the quotient $S^n/_\sim$ with $x\sim x'\Leftrightarrow\begin{cases}x=x'\\ x=-x'\end{cases}$

Graphically this equivalence relation "cuts" the sphere in "half". Is this right? For example $S^2/_\sim$ would be just one half of $S^2$.

I give our definition of "overlapping" and "trivial set":

A continuous function $p:Y\to X$ is called "overlapping", if for every $x\in X$ exists an open neighbourhood $U\subseteq X$, such that $p^{-1}(U)$ is a disjoint union of open sets, which are mapped to $U$ by $p$ homeomorphic.
We call $U$ then a "trivial set".

Now $p: S^n\to S^n/_{\sim}$, $x\mapsto [x]$ is continuous by the quotient-topology.

Now I have to show, that for every $[x]\in S^n/_{\sim}$ a open set $U$ exists with $p^{-1}(U)$ is a disjoint union of open sets, and these sets are mapped homeomorphic to $U$ by $p$.

Since I have to show, that $U_i$ is a "trivial set", I want to show, that every $[x]\in S^n/_{\sim}$ is an element of any $U_i$.

Is this right? Could you help me with that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The English term for your "overlapping function" is a _covering map_, and the "trivial sets" are usually called _evenly covered neighborhoods_.

Answer (score 1):

What (a) is asking you to show is that the quotient map $S^n \to \mathbb{R}P^n$ is a covering map, and that the sets $U_i = \{p(x):x \in S^n, x_i \neq 0\}$ are evenly covered. The way that the $U_i$ are defined makes it quite easy to show that this is the case. Note that each $U_i$ is the image under $p$ of the union of two disjoint homeomorphic open sets, namely the sets $\{x \in S^n: x_i > 0\}$ and $\{x \in S^n: x_i < 0\}$. The covering map $p$ sends both sets to the same image in $\mathbb{R}P^n$, so you only need to show that $p$ is a homeomorphism on these two sets.

For (b), it seems you just need to note (or show, perhaps) that $S^n$ is path connected. But that seems a strange question to ask. I think the idea is that you should show that there is a loop in $\mathbb R P^n$ based at $e$ that lifts to a path from $e$ to $-e$ in $S^n$, and therefore $\mathbb{R} P^n$ is not simply connected.

As a note, $\mathbb{R}P^n$ is not just $S^n$ "cut in half," at least without identifying points along the edge. A hemisphere of $S^n$ is homeomorphic to a disk, while $\mathbb{R} P^n$ is not.

Comment: to a): Thank you. So I have $U_i=\{x\in S^n: x_i>0\}\cup\{x\in S^n:x_i<0\}$. Obviously this is a disjoint union. It is enough to show, that $p:\{x\in S^n:x_i>0\}\to U_i$ is a homeomorphism. I know a theorem, which states, that when $f:X\to Y$ is a continuous bijection and $X$ compact and $Y$ hausdorff. Then $f$ is a homeomorphism. $U_i$ is obvioulsy hausdorff and $p$ a bijection, since $x\mapsto [x]$ and $x_i>0$. Hence $[x]=\{x\}$. I need to show, that  every open cover of $\{x\in S^n:x_i>0\}$ exists a finite subcover.

Comment: There is a problem with that argument: $\{x \in S^n: x_i > 0\}$ is not compact, because it is homeomorphic to an open disk. It would be better to come up with a continuous inverse to $p$ restricted to $\{x \in S^n: x_i > 0\}$.

Comment: Ok, this should be easy, since I already recognised, that $p$ is the "identity". Therfore $p^{-1}: U_i obviously continuous.

Comment: Yes. More specifically, it's one-to-one and a quotient map, so it's a homeomorphism.

Comment: Thank you. It is the same for the other set then. To b) I tried to give a path, in the polar coordinate system, that connects -e and e, but I do not know, how I can generalize it for all dimensions. And unfortunatly I dont get your hint.

Comment: You don't need to use polar coordinates. Instead, pick any point $a$ on the equatorial sphere between $e$ and $-e$. Then you can write a path from $e$ to $a$ like this: $f(t) = ((1-t)e + ta)/|(1-t)e+ta|$. Then write a similar path from $a$ to $-e$ and glue them together.

Comment: Has not to be $f(0)=e$ and $f(1)=a$, to be a path?

Comment: But it is. $f(0) = e/|e| = e/1 = e$ and $f(1) = a/|a| = a/1 = a$.

Comment: Oh, I see. |e|=1=|a| holds, because these are points on the sphere... Sorry, I was thinking about real numbers...

Comment: You note $||.||_2$ as $|.|$ am I right?

Comment: $g(t)=\frac{t(-e)+(1-t)a}{|t(-e)+(1-t)a|}$ should be a path from $a$ to $-e$. Because $g(0)=\frac{a}{|a|}=a$ and $g(1)=\frac{-e}{|-e|}=-e$. Now I glue them together by walking the path "twice as fast" back and forth.